# Setting chromedriver proxy auth with Selenium using Python

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I am coding a test suite using Python and the Selenium library. Using the chromedriver, I am setting proxies using:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % hostname + ":" + port)
global driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

This works fine when the proxy does not have authentication. However, if the proxy requires you to **login with a username and password** it will not work. What is the correct and proper way to pass proxy authentication information to the chromedriver using add_argument or other methods?

It is not the same as: [How to set Proxy setting for Chrome in Selenium Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225507/how-to-set-proxy-setting-for-chrome-in-selenium-java)

Seeing as:

1. I ts a different language
2. Its firefox, not chrome.
3. --proxy-server=http://user:password@proxy.com:8080 does not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451190/how-to-use-authenticated-proxy-in-selenium-chromedriver

Comment: @KirilS. Based on what was said in that topic I'll need some sort of extension in chrome to accomplish this?

Comment: the main thing it says is that unlike Firefox, Chrome uses OS proxy (not its own), so your options are 1 - settings the OS with proper proxy settings before test (good workaround for Windows where you can just setup a special user for selenium testing); 2 - setting OS proxy settings from the test (might be too complicated); 3 - using a special add-on that would allow you to change proxy settings on the fly.

Comment: @KirilS. On unix systems, I am getting: 
Message: unknown error: cannot process extension #1
from unknown error: invalid public key length

Comment: any update on this? this is killing me. Can it be done in Chrome?

Comment: @Toolkit check the answer i just posted and see if it works for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DesiredCapabilities`. I have been successfully using proxy authentication with the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

proxy = {'address': '123.123.123.123:2345',
         'username': 'johnsmith123',
         'password': 'iliketurtles'}


capabilities = dict(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
capabilities['proxy'] = {'proxyType': 'MANUAL',
                         'httpProxy': proxy['address'],
                         'ftpProxy': proxy['address'],
                         'sslProxy': proxy['address'],
                         'noProxy': '',
                         'class': "org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
                         'autodetect': False}

capabilities['proxy']['socksUsername'] = proxy['username']
capabilities['proxy']['socksPassword'] = proxy['password']

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=[path to your chromedriver], desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

EDIT: it unfortunately seems this method no longer works since one of the updated to either Selenium or Chrome since this post. as of now, i do not know another solution, but i will experiment and update this if i find anything out.

Comment: it didn't work for me, I had to use a dynamically generated extension. I will try again in a while. I am using Selenium .NET, may be that is the reason

Comment: there is a typo 5 th line `username` is written as `usernmae`

Comment: This method does'nt work with chromedriver and proxy requiring authentication.

Comment: This method doesnt forward username and password to chrome. Is there any other solution on this?

Comment: @AlexeyTrofimov it unfortunately seems this method no longer works since one of the updated to either Selenium or Chrome since this post. as of now, i do not know another solution, but i will experiment and update this if i find anything out.

Comment: @Stack tagging you so you get notified as well

Comment: @anshaj unfortunatley not, and there probably wont be as the code has changed and likely wont be reverted. however, there is a work around by building a chrome extension through code. [here is a link with details on how](https://botproxy.net/docs/how-to/setting-chromedriver-proxy-auth-with-selenium-using-python/). look at the second section that is titled "HTTP Proxy Authentication with Chromedriver in Selenium"